# pandas: concat rows of strings until specifc characters

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a one column dataframe. The rows of that column contain dialogue that often span multiple rows. At the end of each person's dialogue line is the same combination of characters "&,," as seen below:

```
   Words
1  hello world! &,,
2  I woke up this morning and made some eggs.
3  They tasted good. &,,
```

I want to merge each row that does not end with a "&,," with the next row, so that each row is a different person talking instead of having multiple rows of the same paragraph. It would look like this:

```
   Words
1  hello world! &,,
2  I woke up this morning and made some eggs. They tasted good. &,,
```

Every question I've seen similar to this has involved another column that would specify some extra information, for my example it might say who was talking, but for this dataset I do not have that nor do I have another dataset with more information, all I have is the separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **`join`** your values and **`split`** on your delimiter to recreate your dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    ''.join(df.Words.values)
    .split('&,,'), columns=['Words']
)

                                               Words
0                                      hello world!
1  I woke up this morning and made some eggs.They...
2
```

This can result in empty values if the last column *ends* with `&,,`, but it's easy to filter those rows:

```
df.loc[df.Words.ne('')]

                                               Words
0                                      hello world!
1  I woke up this morning and made some eggs.They...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `df['Words'].str.endswith('&,,')` to find which rows end with `&,,`, then use `cumsum` to generate the desired group numbers (stored below in the `row` column).
Once you have those group numbers, you can use `pd.pivot_table` to reshape the DataFrame into the desired form:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = sys.maxsize

df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Words': ['hello world! &,,',
             'I woke up this morning and made some eggs.',
             'They tasted good. &,,']}, index=[1, 2, 3])

df['row'] = df['Words'].str.endswith('&,,').shift().fillna(0).cumsum() + 1
result = pd.pivot_table(df, index='row', values='Words', aggfunc=' '.join)
print(result)
```

yields

```
                                                                Words
row                                                                  
1                                                    hello world! &,,
2    I woke up this morning and made some eggs. They tasted good. &,,
```